# Labels on left in align environment

Tags: numbering, align

I am using the `align` environment, but wish my numbering of equations to be on the left-hand side of the page. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution, but for the full document is to write the first line as

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}
```